# Reading xls file with Python

Tags: python, xlrd

```
import xlrd
cord = xlrd.open_workbook('MT_coordenadas_todas.xls')

id = cord.sheet_by_index(0)
print id
```

When I run my code in terminal,I got

```
<xlrd.sheet.Sheet object at 0x7f897e3ecf90>
```

I wanted to take the first column,so what should I change in my code?

Comment: you have a reference to the worksheet, and it has a [`col` method](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet.col-method), so `id.col(0)` maybe or `col_values` depending what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id is a reference to the sheet object. You need to use `values = id.col_values(0)` to read the values from the first column of that sheet.